# Issue With ImagePicker And Assigning To ImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I am working through building a small app that allows the user to select an image to append to a post. The user selects the add image (has tap gesture recognizer) and is presented the iOS photo library. Then, the user selects the image and the selected image should replace the default camera image. I am getting the following error when I select an image from the library: `2019-03-16 19:13:09.238959-0400 Spirit-App[34772:2211555] [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}`. I have info.plist setup with [image]

Based on my print statements I am using for debugging, I seem to be entering the imageTapped function but never making it to `@objc func imagePickerController`. Even if I comment out `@objc func imagePickerController` I still receive the error from above. So, two questions:

1. Why am I receiving an error even when I am not assigning the selected image back at the modal page?
2. If I resolve that issue, will the code I have that assigns the image work correctly or does it require changes?

Code:

```
class NewPostViewController: ViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var newPostImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postDescription: UITextView!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        view.isOpaque = false
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tap:)))
        newPostImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        newPostImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func imageTapped(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("BUTTON WORKED!")
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        })

        print("Image Picker Complete")
        newPostImage.image = image
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong signature for the delegate method.

Change:

```
@objc func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
```

to:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
```

You also need to change all of the code inside that delegate:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        newPostImage.image = image
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```